# sql select based on select from the same table

Tags: sql

I have a table, eg LISTS, with a variety of lists in them of Employees.
What I want to do is use the contents of 1 known list (Eg Working_List) to select all other lists that have any of the Employees in Working_List in them.

```
Example - 
Working List contains
1234,
5678.
List1 contains
1234,
2345,
3456.
List2 contains
5678,
6789,
7890.
List3 contains
2345,
4567,
7890.
List4 contains
1234,
7890,
5678.
```

So what I need the SQL to return with the above examples is List1, List2 and List4 (preferably just once)(and Working_List although I can remove this from the select separately).
I'm not a complete novice at SQL, but this is beyond me ...
Thanks
Simon

Comment: Please pick one database.

Comment: Please show your data in a tabular format.  Your data description doesn't really make sense as a table in a database.

Comment: Please show us your tables and database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT L2.List
FROM
    LISTS L1
    JOIN LISTS L2 ON
        L1.List = 'Working List'
        AND L1.Employee = L2.Employee
WHERE L2.List <> 'Working List'
```

Comment: Hi Chris, 
Although this works fine as a SQL statement in its own right, I'm actually trying to invoke this SQL statement from within a separate system which appears not to like Joins & Aliases.
Is it possible for something like this to be done without those ??
Thanks
Simon

Comment: What system is it? I.e. what does it like? :)

Comment: Its ProIV if that helps ...
As far as I understand it, and this is a bit above my head, it needs to be Type 1 SQL level ....

Comment: Where is the data stored? What SQL language are you using to query it?

Comment: The data is stored in an Oracle database table, but I also need the SQL (or a separate statement) to cater for SQL Server. As for SQL Language I can't answer that personally, but as a general rule I test the SQL statements in SQL Developer first, and SQL Server Mgmnt Studio later if that is of any help.

Comment: Hi Chris,
I think I've just stumbled across the answer ... just testing it out and will post back if successful :-)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT LIST
FROM LISTS
WHERE LIST <> 'Working List'
AND EMPLOYEE IN
(SELECT EMPLOYEE FROM LISTS WHERE LIST = 'Working List')

The above works ok, thanks for your assistance in pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Awesome - glad you sorted it!

Answer (score 0):

I could assume only a little of what you're trying to get. It would be great if you could share screenshots of the table you're mentioning. From the brief understanding, i could get from your post I think the following code is as close as I understood it

```
SELECT c.name AS 'ColumnName',
       t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.name LIKE '<YourValue>'
ORDER by TableName
```